# How to extract part of an URL path in regex

Tags: regex, regex-group

In my url that might look like this:

```
protocol://server/path1/path2/path3/pathn/key/id1234567890?Create
```

I want to get the value `id1234567890` (via a group) but I don't know how many "path" parts there are and what they are called.
Currently I use the following regex to find the URL itself in a big text file:

```
protocol\:\/\/[^/]+(\/[^ \t\n\r]+)
```

This regex needs to be extended and give me a chance to capture the id value.
Would be very happy about help :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Following may work.

```
key/(id\d+)\?
```

Apply that for retrieved urls. Simple, but should work :)

**Edit:** Or may be you can apply this derectly.

Answer (score 0):

You could for example match all the forward slashes until the last one, and then capture 1+ word chars in group 1

```
protocol://[^/\r\n]+(?:\/[^\r\n/]+)*/(\w+)
```

*Explanation*

- `protocol://` Match literally
- `[^/\r\n]+` Match 1+ times any char except `/` or a newline
- `(?:\/[^\r\n/]+)*` Repeat 0+ times matching `/`followed by 1+ times any char except `/` or a newline
- `/` Match the last `/`
- `(\w+)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ word chars

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/d9ODG6/1)